# How to import module in the current project from different Directory in Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: angular2-modules

[image]

In The above image `angular2-template` is my Angular 2 project.
I have defined `ContactModule` in the `common-template` folder.
How can I import `ContactModule` from `common-template` into `angular2-template`?

Comment: What error message did you get on your `angular2-template`?

Answer (score -2):

You can't import anything outside of `/src/...`
 that is because the angular2 compiler doesn't look for anything higher than the `src` folder.
You could however copy the ContactModule from the common-template folder into `/angular2-template/src/app` and move implement it into your component/module of choice.

For example:
move `/common-module/commonModuleFolder` to `/angular2-template/src/app/modules/commonModuleFolder`

Then you can go into for example `AppComponent` and import it like this:
`import CommonModule from './modules/commonModuleFolder/common.module'`